# Timeout method after hitting the url

Tags: javascript, ajax

We have the following method to invoke the URL using ajax.
Currently after hitting the url we are using the response.
So we want to put a timeout for reposne.So when we invoke the url if the response didn't came after 2sec then call one more method and if resp comes within two seconds call other mehtod.
We have tried using the timeout,but unable to made it working with the code.

```
  function ajaxCall(url1) {
      var ajaxresp = null;
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
              if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                  ajaxresp = xmlhttp.responseText;

                  //function call
                  getAdResponse(ajaxresp);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Please advice me how to proceed.

Comment: I am presuming this is not how you indent your actual code...

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",url1,true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function (){    
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){     
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200){     
        ajaxresp = xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();
setTimeout(function() {
    if(ajaxresp) {
       dosmth(ajaxresp);
    } else {
       dosmthelse();
    }
}, 2000);
```